# Low memory with 640Kb of live bytes?

Tags: iphone, memory

i've a problem with my application that need to display a lot of images and video.

After running ObjectAlloc tool, i see that the live bytes is 640Kb and the overall memory is 31,54Mb when the application crash.

In the organizer i get a "low memory" report so i guess the app crashed because low memory but the ObjectAllocation data don't make any sense to me...

Any ideas?

This is the Organizer crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: CDCAF38C-CFFD-4316-9C4A-5C8E37794B49
CrashReporter Key:   65390aeb97b2b81076576c3e33b025feb5db9202
OS Version:          iPhone OS 3.1.3 (7E18)
Date:                2010-05-19 10:07:19 +0200

Free pages:        372
Wired pages:       12260
Purgeable pages:   0
Largest process:   DTMobileIS

Processes
         Name                 UUID                    Count resident pages
       ATreeTest <1d51c3a5fef8b747c3a1be9405bdd52a>    1150 (jettisoned) (active)
      DTMobileIS <69c3fa96db2f29474d62964aa1a69bfa>    3316
notification_pro <8a7725017106a28b545fd13ed58bf98c>      68
    mediaserverd <3d3800d6acfff050e4d0ed91cbe2467e>     464 (jettisoned)
         syslogd <8eddddc00294d5615afded36ee3f1b62>      56 (jettisoned)
            apsd <32070d91b216d806973c8f1b1d8077a4>     173
     SpringBoard <324939a437d1cca1fa4af72d9f5d0eba>    2475 (jettisoned) (active)
      accessoryd <8f21c8b376d16e2ccb95ed6d21d8317a>      99 (jettisoned)
notification_pro <8a7725017106a28b545fd13ed58bf98c>      64
            ptpd <f5e735bffd0557fcdc53cb35b6d9ce66>     129
         notifyd <591dd4dd804b4b8741f52335ea1fa4ab>      64
      CommCenter <b4b87526ae086bb62c982f1078f43f81>     167
         configd <85efd41aceac34ccc0019df76623c7a9>     294
       fairplayd <a2eaf736b3e07c7c9a2c82e9eb893555>      91
   mDNSResponder <df1cd275e4ad434e0575990e8e1da4cb>     101
       lockdownd <80d2bd44c0bcca273d48ce52010f7e65>     285
         launchd <a5988245aade809bf77576f1d9de42c5>      71



**End**
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ObjectAlloc` instrument does not display the full memory usage of your application, particularly if you have a lot of user interface elements that you are dealing with.  For a more accurate reading of your application's total memory footprint at any given time, use the `Memory Monitor` instrument instead.  You will see that your application is indeed exceeding the memory threshold on the device.''

You can add the `Memory Monitor` instrument by clicking on the Library button of the toolbar in Instruments. A list of all the available instruments appears, and you drag `Memory Monitor` onto the Instruments area of the main window.

If you combine the `Memory Monitor` instrument with the `ObjectAlloc` one, you should be able to track what is triggering memory spikes within your application.  Select the `Track inspection head` option for the Memory Monitor (below the Instruments list; click on Memory Manager first to activate the tool, the options will appear on the bottom pane) to view the recorded memory size of your application at any point in its execution.

Comment: Ok thanks - great tips. Real memory starts out at 137MB on load without doing anything. That is really high right? So now I'm looking around using the Allocations and then the CallTree subsection. I finally see figures that match the 137MB. All the heavy hitters in the memory department as I look down the call tree are these rendering classes that spit out images. I am using CGContextRef and drawing and all that and then at the end spitting out and returning an UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked] and releasing everything.

Comment: I can't understand if this is accurate or not. Other answers say that the 'real memory' include memory blocks already released, but the OS hasn't reclaimed yet (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8797272/287403). So is that correct or not? Should I be worrying about my 10mb 'Live Bytes' in Object Allocation or my 80+mb 'Real Memory' in Memory Monitor?

Comment: @BobSpryn - I can tell you from experience that the memory usage reported by Memory Monitor seems pretty much on the ball. On older devices, memory warnings fire the instant I cross certain thresholds as measured by this instrument. I provide a little more explanation of the difference between the Allocations and Memory Monitor instruments in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5627221/19679